# The requested URL / was not found on this server Apache Windows7

Tags: apache

I am having issue while setting up virtual localhosts in my httpd.conf. What i write

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "C:/Users/user/Documents/dispatcher/cache"
  <Directory C:/Users/user/Documents/dispatcher/cache>
    <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
      SetHandler dispatcher-handler
      ModMimeUsePathInfo On
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My apache version is 2.2.21. Error is :

```
[Mon Jan 25 22:46:17 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Attempt to serve directory: C:/Users/user/Documents/dispatcher/cache/
```

Comment: So what is the server name (it is commented out here...) and have you added that address to your `hosts` file as being a local address?

Comment: i have 127.0.0.1 localhost  in my hosts file. and un commented servername, but still same issue.